# Finding an alternative way for CTE in sql : Performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, sqlperformance

> [image: Blockquote]

I have a table in which 16M records are there. I'm trying to use below query to find required result using CTE, But it takes more than 45 Minuit's to run the query. Now should i break the query or is there any alternative for below query ?

```
 DELETE  FROM Table1
    WHERE   IDD_Memid = @memid;  


    WITH    CTE_Example(MJD_Introducer, MJD_memid, Depth, MJD_doj, mjd_lr)  
              AS (SELECT    MJD_Introducer, MJD_MemID, 0 AS Depth, MJD_DOJ,  
                            MJD_LR  
                  FROM      Table2
                  WHERE     MJD_MemID = '10000001'  
                  UNION ALL  
                  SELECT    MJD_Introducer,  
                            MJD_MemID,  
                            CTE_Example.Depth + 1 AS Depth,
                            MJD_DOJ,  
                            MJD_LR  
                  FROM      Table2
                  JOIN      CTE_Example ON Table2.MJD_Introducer = CTE_Example.MJD_memid)  
        INSERT  INTO Table1(IDD_MEMID, IDD_DOWNID,  
                                             IDD_LEVEL)  
                SELECT  @memid AS 'IDD_MEMID', MJD_memid AS 'IDD_DOWNID',  
                        Depth AS 'IDD_LEVEL'  
                FROM    CTE_Example  
                WHERE   CTE_Example.MJD_memid <> @memid  
                ORDER BY CTE_Example.Depth, CTE_Example.MJD_memid   
        OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 30000);
```

Comment: Can you post the execution plan

Comment: Using `WHILE` is an old alternative way ;).

Comment: Have shared execution plan now.

Comment: MAXRECURSION 30000... I see that your deleting and then inserting again. I don't know your goal, but perhaps there is a different way. This does seem like a one time only query, so perhaps it's acceptable that it last a bit longer. Future inserts should just do `IDD_LEVEL + 1` so you don't need recursion anymore.

Comment: Well - I'd say the first obvious question is which problem you're trying to solve that requires you do to recursion in the database? Often recursion is not needed to solve problems.

Comment: I want to traverse the down-line of each member from Table1. That's why i did it with recursion.